# Reading Excel via COM interop

Tags: excel, com

My coworker have made a srcript that open excel and read values from it. But it has problem it read the value as i see it in the file. I have value 9.12345678 depending on the column size it returns 9.1, 9 and so on. He uses the Text propertie. I have tried using Value and Value2 but no efffect i cannot get 9.12345678.  Any Ideas ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uncheck [Precision as displayed](https://support.office.com/en-IE/article/Set-rounding-precision-e5d707e3-07a8-4df2-810c-218c531eb06a) and use `Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS Gerg said on  Workbook object you set

xlBook.PrecisionAsDisplayed := FALSE;

And then on the range Object 
You use the .Value Many thanks